# Getting 400 Bad Request for Spring RestTemplate POST

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I want to consume Spring Rest web-service, using POST method. I don't have access to POJO file at client end (website), so have to use JSON at client end and POJO at web-service. Below is my code:

**REST Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/updateAdmin", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json", headers="Accept=application/json")
public ResponseEntity<String> updateAdmin(@RequestBody Ss_admin admin) {
    try {
        ss_admin_dao.updateAdmin(admin);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

**POJO**

```
package model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Ss_admin implements Serializable {
@JsonProperty("a_id")
private long a_id;
@JsonProperty("a_username")
private String a_username;
@JsonProperty("a_password")
private String a_password;

public Ss_admin() {}
public long getA_id() {
    return a_id;
}
public void setA_id(long a_id) {
    this.a_id = a_id;
}
public String getA_username() {
    return a_username;
}
public void setA_username(String a_username) {
    this.a_username = a_username;
}
public String getA_password() {
    return a_password;
}
public void setA_password(String a_password) {
    this.a_password = a_password;
}
}
```

**REST Client**

```
try {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> list = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
        list.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        restTemplate.setMessageConverters(list);
        //restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(HttpClientBuilder.create().build()));
        String url = "http://localhost:8181/xyz/updateAdmin";
        JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("a_username", "testabcd");
        obj.put("a_id", 1);
        obj.put("a_password", "N/A");
        json.put(obj);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        //headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        //headers.setAccept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        headers.add("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString());
        headers.add("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString());
        //headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(obj.toString(), headers);
        restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);

        //restTemplate.postForEntity(url, entity, String.class);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

As you can see in the commented, I have tried many options with no success.

**Stack Trace**

```
Aug 04, 2017 6:58:12 PM org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate handleResponseError
WARNING: POST request for "http://localhost:8181/xyz/updateAdmin" resulted in 400 (Bad Request); invoking error handler
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
at  org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:576)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:532)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:489)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:431)
at webcontroller.TestController.update(TestController.java:77)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:748)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:931)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:822)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:807)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**EDIT**
I had tested REST web-service `http://localhost:8181/xyz/updateAdmin`
 using Postman, and it is successfully executing, but not working with RestTemplate.

**ISSUE SOLVED**
See my answer below.

Comment: I also had a bad request 400 using method postForObject of RestTemplate.  The reason was on my pojo, I did not use @JsonProperty to annotate each field.  Basically, before the fix, the contents of the pojo were not being sent to the endpoint.  This was verified if you remove the body of the json request in postman.  Sending an empty body also gives you a 400.  That was the clue to then narrow in on the pojo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just solved the issue by adding following code in dispatcher servlet configuration file of REST Client:

```
<bean id="jacksonMessageConverter"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Full code of dispatcher servlet is:
**web-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">
<context:component-scan base-package="webcontroller" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
  <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="jacksonMessageConverter"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

Also removed some code from REST calling function, below are the changes:
**REST CLIENT**

```
try {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String url = "http://localhost:8181/xyz/updateAdmin";
        JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("a_username", "testabcd");
        obj.put("a_id", 1);
        //obj.put("a_password", "N/A");
        json.put(obj);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString());
        headers.add("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString());
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(obj.toString(), headers);
        restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);


    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried without '/' in value?

```
@RequestMapping(value="updateAdmin", method=RequestMethod.POST, 
consumes="application/json", headers="Accept=application/json")
public ResponseEntity<String> updateAdmin(@RequestBody Ss_admin admin) 
{
    try {
        ss_admin_dao.updateAdmin(admin);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```